# How to group and count by date and 8-hr interval on those dates in datetime SQL column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column `visit_date` that is a `datetime` object with format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS` that looks like the following:

```
visit_date         |visit_id
-------------------|-----
2010-11-01 00:02:00|92314
2010-11-01 23:05:21|23498
2010-11-01 12:42:31|12343
2010-11-02 05:13:21|79881
2010-11-02 14:35:15|22134
2010-11-02 16:12:23|12348
2010-11-03 01:22:44|12384
2010-11-03 05:23:41|12394
2010-11-03 15:13:55|99384
```

I would like to group by date and by 8-hr window on that date such that I have:

```
interval           |count
-------------------|-----
2010-11-01 00:00:00|1
2010-11-01 08:00:00|2
2010-11-01 16:00:00|3
2010-11-02 00:00:00|4
2010-11-02 08:00:00|5
2010-11-02 16:00:00|6
2010-11-03 00:00:00|7
2010-11-03 08:00:00|8
2010-11-03 16:00:00|9
```

My original query (using only dates) was:

```
SELECT CAST(visit_date as DATE), count(1) as count
FROM table
GROUP BY CAST(visit_date as DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(visit_date as DATE)
```

But that only groups by date.

Is there a recommended way to get interval counts for each interval per day? I have seen implementations using `DATEADD` and `DATEPART` but not sure which makes the most sense in this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: How can you make `count` column? I don't see any logic in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the hours in to what you group and count:

```
SELECT 
  CAST(visit_date as DATE), 
  HOUR(visit_date)/8 as ival8h
  count(1) as count
FROM table
  GROUP BY CAST(visit_date as DATE), HOUR(visit_date)/8
  ORDER BY CAST(visit_date as DATE)
```

The hour function returns the hour number of the passed date, divide it by 8 to get an int of the interval, so 0 to 7 becomes 0, 8 to 16 becomes 1 etc

If you want it back as a time pegged to a round 8h multiply it by 8 again and format it to NN:00:00, or add it to the date, thus:

```
SELECT 
  DATEADD(hour, (HOUR(visit_date)/8)*8, CAST(CAST(visit_date as DATE) as DATETIME) as quantized_date,
  count(1) as count
FROM table
  GROUP BY DATEADD(hour, (HOUR(visit_date)/8)*8, CAST(CAST(visit_date as DATE) as DATETIME)
  ORDER BY CAST(visit_date as DATE)
```

This basically rounds the hours down to the lesser 8h market and adds that to midnight. Two casts are required (probably) on the date because DATEADD won't add hours to a date, only a datetime but we need the cast to date to peg the tine element to midnight

If you want there to be a date and a 0 count for periods where no events took place, use a numbers table or row generator and create a sequence of dates to left join your real data onto, then count the real data grouped by the fake dates

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense. To reformat it, would I simply substitute `HOUR(visit_date)/8 as ival8h` with `FORMAT(HOUR(visit_date), '##:00:00')`?

Comment: `Hour(visit_date)/8` should give 0 1 or 2, so I think you'll need to multiply it by 8 again to get 0 8 or 16 and `format(.., '00":00:00"') `- FORMAT obeys the .net formatting system so any literal text is surrounded by speech marks, the first 00 being used to pad the number out to double digits

Comment: That being said, you could alternatively `date_add` your `(hour(visit_date)/8)*8` hours to your `cast(visit_date as date)` (midnight) if you want to keep it as a datetime or work with it further

Comment: Added a second query implementing the above

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross apply` to form 4 shift boundary values, then use those in a `case expression` to genertate the `group by` values

```
SELECT
      case
         when visit_date >= s1 and visit_date < s2 then s1 
         when visit_date >= s2 and visit_date < s3 then s2
         when visit_date >= s3 and visit_date < s4 then s3 
      end as shift
    , count(1) as count
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY (
    select 
          cast(CAST(visit_date as DATE)as datetime) s1
        , dateadd(hh,8,cast(CAST(visit_date as DATE)as datetime)) s2
        , dateadd(hh,16,cast(CAST(visit_date as DATE)as datetime)) s3
        , dateadd(hh,24,cast(CAST(visit_date as DATE)as datetime)) s4  
    ) ca
GROUP BY
      case
         when visit_date >= s1 and visit_date < s2 then s1 
         when visit_date >= s2 and visit_date < s3 then s2
         when visit_date >= s3 and visit_date < s4 then s3 
      end
ORDER BY shift
```

result:

```
+----+---------------------+-------+
|    |        shift        | count |
+----+---------------------+-------+
|  1 | 01.11.2010 00:00:00 |     1 |
|  2 | 01.11.2010 08:00:00 |     1 |
|  3 | 01.11.2010 16:00:00 |     1 |
|  4 | 02.11.2010 00:00:00 |     1 |
|  5 | 02.11.2010 08:00:00 |     1 |
|  6 | 02.11.2010 16:00:00 |     1 |
|  7 | 03.11.2010 00:00:00 |     2 |
|  8 | 03.11.2010 08:00:00 |     1 |
+----+---------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the canonical way in SQL Server is to use `dateadd()` and `datediff()`:

```
select dateadd(hour, 0, 3 * (datediff(hour, 0, visit_date) / 3)) as day_hour8,
       count(*)
from t
group by dateadd(hour, 0, 3 * (datediff(hour, 0, visit_date) / 3))
order by day_hour8;
```